# Signal-r android working on iis express but not in iis 10 on windows server 2019

Tags: android, asp.net-core, iis, signalr

I used signalR on android with asp.net core 2.2. It's working well on iis express (Visual studio 2019) when I call the hub `hubConnection.send("Send", message);` on my android client. But when I deploy the asp.net core on iis 10 (windows server 2019), I have the following error message :

`Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected'.` and the connection state is `DISCONNECTED`.

My android client code :

```
HubConnection hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("server IP @").build();
try {
    hubConnection.start();
    //I added the following line to restart the hubConnection when disconnected for whatever reason but in vain ;-(
    if (!hubConnection.getConnectionState().toString().trim().equals("CONNECTED"))
        hubConnection.start();            
    hubConnection.send("Send", message);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Erreur hubconnection ", e.getMessage());            
}
```

Android SignalR version 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:1.0.0'.
Asp.net core (2.2) SignalR version : 1.1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `hubConnection.start()` does not mean you have connected right away. `hubConnection.start()` returns [io.reactivex.Completable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html) to which you should subscribe creating `CompletableObserver`. This observer will receive a response when you either connected or failed to connect. Then and only after a successful connection, you will be able to send a message.

```
HubConnection hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("127.0.0.1").build();
Completable connecting = hubConnection.start();
connecting.subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            // Called once by the Completable to set a Disposable 
            // on this instance which then can be used to cancel 
            // the subscription at any time.
            Log.d(TAG, " onSubscribe : " + d.isDisposed());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            // Connected     
            hubConnection.send("Send", message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d(TAG, " onError : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

One more hint: use [HubConnectionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.signalr.hubconnectionstate?view=aspnet-signalr-java) enum to check connection state instead of using this construction which can break on any further update:

```
hubConnection.getConnectionState().toString().trim().equals("CONNECTED")
```

It can be replaced with:

```
hubConnection == HubConnectionState.CONNECTED
```

When you need to check whether you are disconnected:

```
hubConnection == HubConnectionState.DISCONNECTED
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and +1 for the hint. now there is no error message but the connection state is still DISCONNECTED and nothing happened.

Comment: Make sure your server is reachable.

Comment: Now I have `There were no compatible transports on the server. DISCONNECTED` error message.

Comment: The issue is on the server. Is the server you are connecting to available to the public? If it is your own server implementation you can upload it to GitHub, **if there is nothing private**, and send a link here in comments. I'll check it out.

Comment: You were right the issue is on server. I read on [MS SignalR web site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2#known-limitations) the known limitiation among them _Only the WebSockets transport is supported_. So I went to the server and install the Websocket Protocol features of IIS and Voila! it works. Thanks for your support

Comment: @ASM, you are welcome. If you think the answer fixed client-side issue accept the answer to help others to find it. If not - then don't. I actually saw an issue in your initial client-side implementation, so basically you had one issue on each side.

Comment: @ASM hi, I have the same problem. could you share where you get the websocket protocol?

Comment: @SulaimanTriarjo, on windows non server go to : Turn Windows features on/off-> IIS->WWW service->App. devpt. features->Websocket Protcol. On Windows server go to add roles and features and I think the steps are the same.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jenea suggested, The issue is on the server. So I found out on  [MS SignalR web site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2#known-limitations) that there are some known limitations among them *Only the WebSockets transport is supported*. So I went to the server and install the **Websocket Protocol** features of IIS and it works. 
 To install the Websocket Protocol  :

Go to *Add roles and features* on Windows server and on *Web Server
(IIS)*  go to *Web Server* -> *Application Development* and tick Websocket Protocol.